# JQUERY, AJAX if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I try to make a simple chat bot. So far the bot answer is user type in defined question. But how can I make it that the chatbot gives out a "sorry I don't understand" if user ask something that is not defined?

```
function ai(message){
    if (username.length<3){
        username = message;
        send_message("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you today?");
        responsiveVoice.speak("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you today?");
    } 

    if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("how are you")>=0){
        send_message("Thanks, Iam good!");
        responsiveVoice.speak("Thanks, Iam good!");
    }

    if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("time")>=0){
        var date = new Date();
        var h = date.getHours();
        var m = date.getMinutes();
        send_message("Current time is "+h+":"+m);
    }

    if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("thanks")>=0){
        send_message("You are welcome");
    }

    if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("Thank you")>=0){
        send_message("No Problem");
    }

    if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("thank you very much")>=0){
        send_message("Welcome Sir!");          
    } 
}
```

Comment: Early returns from `if`s when defined, and the last line in the function sends "sorry" message?

Comment: do you have a example? I don't understand how to return early?

Comment: ??? Just put `return` as a last line in an `if` block.

Comment: Notice, that `swicth` is often used when you're not sure what is the value to compare to. Please try to implement Gothdo's second example, it's a cleaner way, though you can compare with a single rule only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `else`?

```
if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("how are you")>=0){
  send_message("Thanks, Iam good!");
  responsiveVoice.speak("Thanks, Iam good!");
} else {
  send_message("sorry I don't understand");
  responsiveVoice.speak("sorry I don't understand");
}
```

You can also use [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement:

```
switch (message.toLowerCase()) {
  case "how are you":
    send_message("Thanks, Iam good!");
    responsiveVoice.speak("Thanks, Iam good!");
    break;
  case "something else":
    send_message("something else");
    responsiveVoice.speak("something else");
    break;
  default:
    send_message("sorry I don't understand");
    responsiveVoice.speak("sorry I don't understand");
}
```

Comment: I  updated my code above. I tried ELSE in your example but it did not worked since I have multiply IF's.  Your SWITCH didn't work too. I use jquery 1

Comment: So use it like this: `if () {} else if () {} else if () {} else {}`. And show your `switch` code.

Answer (score 0):

answer provided by Teemu

```
 function ai(message){
            if (username.length<3){
                username = message;
                send_message("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you today?");
                responsiveVoice.speak("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you today?");
                return;
            } 

            if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("how are you")>=0){
                send_message("Thanks, Iam good!");
                responsiveVoice.speak("Thanks, Iam good!");
                return;
            }

            if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("time")>=0){
                var date = new Date();
                var h = date.getHours();
                var m = date.getMinutes();
                send_message("Current time is "+h+":"+m);
                return;
            }

             if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("thanks")>=0){
                send_message("You are welcome");
                 return;
            }

             if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("Thank you")>=0){
                send_message("No Problem");
                 return;
            }

             if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("thank you very much")>=0){
                send_message("Welcome Sir!"); 
            } else {
  send_message("sorry I don't understand");
  responsiveVoice.speak("sorry I don't understand");
}
```